# Algorithms for indefinite symmetric eigenvalue problems

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to learn more about algorithms which deal with the following problems:

Given a symmetric positive semi-definite matrices $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$, with $\lambda_{min}(A) = 0$ find the minimum eigenvalue of the matrix $C = A - B$. This can be framed as minimizing the Rayleigh quotient:
$$ \rho(v) = \min_v \frac{v^T C v}{v^T v} $$
Note that the matrix $C$ is actually indefinite. There are quite a few algorithms for solving this kind of problems when $C$ is PSD (like for instance LOBPCG). However, I can't seem to find much literature on how to solve this for a general $C$ or if there is anyway to exploit the structure of the problem.

Comment: https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611971163?mobileUi=0&

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about really exploiting the structure, but the following seems to work fine:

1. Compute the maximal eigenvalue $\lambda_B$ of $B$ (this can be done fast by iterative methods).
2. Note that the minimal eigenvalue of $C=A-B$ is at least $-\lambda B.$ So, take $C + 2\lambda_B I$. It will be positive definite, so you can use your favorite algorithm for positive definite matrices (conjugate gradient?) At the end, subtract $2\lambda_B$ from the result.